# Create a function that exhibits the same behaviour as of “new” (constructor) keyword in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given:

```js
const obj = new SampleClass(param1);
console.log(obj.passedParam1); // displays the value of passed parameter
```

Expected:

```js
const  obj = myNew(SampleClass, param1);
console.log(obj.passedParam1); // displays the value of passed parameter
```

Where
`SampleClass`(only for eg.) can be any Class of which we want to construct objects.

Please help i am learning js I know concepts of new , objects , proto but unable to think logic for this so please suggest a way , how to implement this, so i can learn something new from community.

Thanks in advance..!!!!

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Comment: sir i am unable to think logic that how to change the functionality of javascript or say how can i implement a function which will work as new constructor, so any hints would be appreciable so i can try to implement

Comment: This sounds like homework or some coding challenge. You must have written some code for `myNew`? It's a function which takes 2 arguments. The first one is the constructor function which needs to be used with `new` and the second one is the argument that needs to be passed to that constructor. The object created needs to returned from the `myNew` function

Comment: There are more ways to create an object in JS, a constructor function is not the only, take a look at [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 1):

Below is one of the ways through which you can achieve what you are looking for

```js
class SampleClass {
  constructor(param) {
    this.param = param;
  }
}

const myNew = (Class, ...params) => {
  return new Class(...params);
}

const sample = new SampleClass("Hello World");
console.log("using new: ", sample.param);

const sampleClass = myNew(SampleClass, "Hello");
console.log("using myNew:", sampleClass.param);
```

Comment: Nitpick: it’s not the “`className`” you pass in, it’s the actual class itself…

Comment: Yes @deceze I agree, but then I cannot use `class` as param name as its a JS keyword. I have renamed it.